# Assigning values to variables in ksh

Tags: ksh

I am trying to find out a way to assign values to variables from a file.
My file has

```
PID=1
VALUE=1000
CMD=/usr/bin/ls -l
```

i want to assign right part of "=" symbol as value to the left side name, This leftside name should be treated like variable name.

It should be like when i print $PID, i should get 1 , when i print $VALUE i should get 1000, when i print $CMD i should get /usr/bin/ls -l ,
I tried using eval, but didn't work. Any help is appreciated ??.

Answer (score 1):

use `.` in front the call to the file. This execute the file in current shell

```
. YourFile
echo $PID

1
```

But this will fail for the CMD because this is not a correct string (not quoted) nor an action (not back quote or eval or `$( )` so be carrefull to use this.
A solution (basic, no controlm on content type and format after the `=`) is :

```
sed -n -e '/[[:alnum:]_]\{1,\}=/ s/=\(.*\)$/="\1"/p' YourFile > /tmp/ToVar.tmp
. /tmp/ToVar.tmp
rm /tmp/ToVar.tmp
```